# MediaStore.Audio.Media provider change notification

Tags: android

I am working on a music app that notifies the user when a new audio file is added to a device.


I read that `Content Observers` are designed to listen for changes in `Content Providers`. However, most of the blogs and guides I read suggest that one should unregister the observer to avoid memory leaks. 

What I planned to do initially was to register the observer for `MediaStore.Audio.Media`. In its `onChange` callback I planned to show the notification.


What is the best practice for monitoring the provider even when my app is stopped?

Moreover, is there a way to listen only for new rows being added to the provider?